# SlikNav multi-level menu on desktop view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slicknav

I'm using **SlikNav** to make a mobile navigation menu. I have this structure:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This works fine on mobile view, here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzOJOv).

My desktop version of this is simply: `nav ul li { display:inline; }` which makes the list display inline.

My question, is it possible for **SlickNav** to make the dropdown menu also work in desktop view?

Comment: Hello, your question is too vague.  What exactly happens on mobile that does **not** happen on the desktop (and vice versa)?

Comment: @AlexanderDixon SlickNav dropdown appears to only work on mobile view e.g., the `<ul>` under `<a href="#">Products</a>` initially appears hidden and is only revealed when clicked (which is the expected behavior). This does not happen on desktop.

Comment: They look the same to me both in mobile and desktop

Comment: Can you provide a screen to show how you expect this

Comment: Have you deployed your code on any server ? If yes, then please share the link. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

right now, the menu is already a dropdown in desktop mode and also in mobile mode..

Just for looks good, do that - 
add a class "sub" in ul after li.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="#">Child1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Child2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and css -

```
li{
  float: left;
}
li > ul.sub{
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this but I have an alternative and fast solution from this.

You can use [smartmenu Plugin](https://www.odcprinters.com/lib/jquery.smartmenus.min.js) Here is the Example [Click Here](https://www.odcprinters.com/)
[image: Preview]

[image: Javascript Code]

[image: HTML Code]

Hope It Helps You.